# How to correctly subset a dataframe in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I want to subset a dataframe, and the following creates a dataframe:

```
col1<-c(1:22 )
col2<-c(0,-19,1,-30,15,60,15,16,19
        ,19,1,13,13,24,60,19,160,72
        ,10,19,14,-78)
col3<-c ( NA,2.190,NA,NA, -5.000, NA,
         1.700,4.220,NA,NA,NA,2.000,
         6.340,9.000,-5.000,NA,4.750,
         NA,NA,NA,2.560,2.560)
mydata<-data.frame(col1,col2,col3)
```

I want to subset this dataframe that both the values in `col2` and `col3` are larger than `0`, then my next syntax is:

```
mydata<-mydata[mydata$col2>0 & mydata$col3>0,]
```

Obviously the dataframe has been changed, so What is the problem with my syntax?

This is the dataframe **before**:

[image: my dataframe before]

... and this is the dataframe **after**:

[image: my dataframe after]

Comment: Use `which()`, e.g. `mydata[which(mydata$col2>0 & mydata$col3>0),]`

Comment: Thank you @MaratTalipov, it perfectly works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the `subset` function:

```
subset(mydata, col2>0 & col3>0)
```

Comment: When something does not work, I usually go back to the basics :)